# site collection Creation time?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

How to find the creation date & time of the site-collection in sharepoint 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPSite object's RootWeb (SPWeb) has a Created property.

Comment: Is that not possible using stsadm?

Comment: Accessing the objectmodel is possible using Powershell.